# How to import CSV files in Rails with mongoid without rigid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, import, mongoid

I'm working on a Rails 4.2 application which needs to import test results into MongoDB database. I'm using mongoid as the mapper. I found few articles on CSV import from which most useful was [RailsCasts - Importing csv and excel #396](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel).

My problem is that my test results do not have a set number of columns, the number is changing depending on the experient, and names of the columns change as well so it is and will be dynamic. There is only few keys/columns which will be present in all documents/rows.

Currently I just use mongoimport and query this with mongo console but I want to tie up these results with the rest of related data which is gaining shape as a Rails application.

I would appreciate if somebody pushed me in the right direction with the rails model for this and a method of importing.

Comment: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-populate-database-using-data.html may help you

Comment: @RAJ this link you provided is not really on the subject as not related to mongoid or even MongoDB

Comment: As you are using Rails, you don't need to worry about your DB type. YOu just need to specify adapter & rest Mapper with handle.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for apparently is [Dynamic Attributes](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields). I followed the RailsCast mentioned in the question and added one line to my Result model so now it starts like this:

```
class Result
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
```

And that's it. It imported all my results from CSV file and I can query them from rails console. Now I just have to figure out how to display them not knowing what some of the attributes might be called.